# How to make PMD's custom java ruleset returns result by category

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, pmd

I'm using the PMD plugins in Android Studio. I don't want to use all their default rules, so I was thinking about making the custom rulesets by creating a xml file, say `All.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="myruleset"
        xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 https://pmd.sourceforge.io/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <description>My custom ruleset to exclude</description>

    <rule ref="category/java/bestpractices.xml">
        <exclude name="JUnit4SuitesShouldUseSuiteAnnotation"/> <!-- I would use this exclude tag for all of the rule that I don't want-->
    </rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/design.xml">
        <!-- Exclude here-->
    </rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/documentation.xml">
        <!-- Exclude here-->
    </rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/performance.xml">
        <!-- Exclude here-->
    </rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/multithreading.xml">
        <!-- Exclude here-->
    </rule>
    <rule ref="category/java/performance.xml">
        <!-- Exclude here-->
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

The problem is that by running the check from Tools -> Run PMD -> Custom Rules -> All, the result is grouped by one (grouped by custom rule file name):
[image]

while using `All` option from the default scan Tools -> Run PMD -> Pre Defined -> All (there are more categories beside All), the result is divided into groups (which is what I need):

[image]

Is there any way I can both exclude unnecessary rules and keep the result categorized?

Thank you for your time.